# JDBC Connection to DB2?

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

We have AS/400 machines from IBM (P8), which uses DB2 database. I want to read the tables from DB2 with a JDBC connection and process it. It is possible to connect to the DB2 database and make sql statements with java program? If yes, can someone show a little sample. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://jt400.sourceforge.net/ <-- look at this

Comment: jt400 is the JDBC driver you need. You can use it with Java, or with applications like SQuirreL to access DB2 for i. BTW, the Power 8 machines are not AS/400's, that is like calling a modern Intel computer a DOS machine. The hardware is `Power Systems`, and the OS is `IBM i`.

Answer (score 1):

Examples and tutorial for iSeries jdbc are on the Db2 for i  documentation available [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzaha/jdbcgets.htm):